# How can I track which links I go to in chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, html, hyperlink

I am clicking a button on a site and I want to see what link it's actually executing.  However the button is simply something like this...

```
<input type="image" name="btnNav1" id="btnNav1" title="view older" src="img/site/prev-ribbon.jpg" alt="view older">
```

so there is now "href" tag.  Is the a chrome extension or a method to record the event once I click the button and see what the "link" being executed is?  Or is this some time of server side activity that cannot be monitored?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: You cannot easily do it.

The link is being generated via JavaScript or other scripting language most likely, and as such you won't get much to tell you where is goes. Trying to think of a way to track this in all circumstances is basically giving me a headache - you can get the individual links from the JS, but that is a lot of extra work, and probably not worth it unless you have a real need to know this info.

HTH, I know it isn't the answer you wanted.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I figured this the likely "answer".  A follow up question to your answer - What tools can help me track down the javascript? Anything other than using the chrome developer tools? Thanks!